# Jupyter notebook has forbidden me from saving by notebooks and token authentification enabled? How do I fix?

Tags: python, google-chrome, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, basic-authentication

I had some malware in my google search so I decided to reset chrome while I was happily coding on Jupyter.

Now Anaconda doesn't even launch, Jupyter has shut down everything and I have forbidden access to by notebooks or saving any of the open ones.

I understand it is related to token authentification being enabled but I don't how to going about getting rid of it or saving the files open on my desktop.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: If you try running Jupyter from your conda prompt what error do you get?

Comment: No error. It opens. The thing is that I can't save anything. And all my open files have forbidden access.

Comment: What browser are you using to open Jupyter?

Comment: Im using Chrome. I managed to copy paste my work into a new file which, having relaunched anaconda it allowed me to save, (the original one it still doesnt). . Im not sure if the issue is fixed or not, I suspect not totally and I still have the token issue. Not sure how to disable it.

Comment: Take a look at this feed - there are several solutions that appear to have helped many people: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2396